# Variables and session variables not working in php includes

Tags: php, variables, include

OK.. forgive me,  there are a couple similar questions posted already with the correct responses... I knew someday I would have to ask the people of the internet for help but I never thought it would be something so stupid...

here is my code.. so far..

index.php:

```
include "http://www.mywebsite.com/shared.php";
$page = "homepage";

include "http://www.mywebsite.com/htmlheader.php"; //trying to use "page" variable in here
echo ("<br>test2: " . $_SESSION['test']);
include "http://www.mywebsite.com/htmlfooter.php";
```

shared.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "what the f_ck im scared";
```

htmlheader.php:

```
echo ("test1: " . $page . "<br>" . $_SESSION['test']);
```

Output right now is:

test1:

test2:

(so the pages are being included.. just not able to use the variables..) From what I understand in its current state this should be printing something like:

test1: what the f_ck im scared

test2: homepagewhat the f_ck im scared

..The funny thing is I was not having any issue with the include using the variable. I had added some things but then it randomly stopped working so I reduced it down to this to try and figure out what the problem was.. I am assuming I have made some silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have started the session with `session_start();`

also check whether `allow_url_fopen` or `allow_url_include` or both have been set to 0 (disabled) in php.ini. if yes try to activate it

```
include "htmlheader.php";
```

instead of

```
include "http://www.mywebsite.com/htmlheader.php";
```

Comment: +1 For mentioning `allow_url_include` and encouraging the use of local includes; that will probably do the trick. However, `session_start()` has nothing to do with the issue, as the example he provided has only a single page.

Comment: @Renato without session_start(), how the session get initialize ?

Comment: The `$_SESSION['test']` variable - as any other variable - will exist until the page is left. Using `session_start()` would just make that variable available to other pages, but that's not the problem here, since there's only one page (index.php).

Comment: thank you for your response, I checked allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include -  they are both enabled, I also added session_start() just to be sure. Good suggestions however I am still unable to use the variables, any other ideas?

Comment: OK, thank you.. you were correct, I overlooked the most important part of your response: I had to change my includes to "../header.php" etc. Now my issue is that I need to use absolute paths when including files (for a number of reasons) Is there a way to use absolute paths and still be able to use the variables?  should I start a new thread?    **I am unable to vote due to lack of reputation points, I would ask the fair people of the internet to upvote the gentleman.

Comment: yes there is a way to get absolute path have look at  here http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Answer (score 0):

ensure you have `session_start();` at the top of the page that is including the `includes`

Comment: hey,  thanks for your response. Unfortunately in this context I don't believe it will be necessary however I added it anyways (I will need it later). I am still unable to access the variables,   any other ideas?